# gitlab-runner docker exeuctor (dind) - Error https://docker:2375/v1.40/info dial tcp: lookup docker on

Tags: docker, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

Ive an issue with gitlab-runner executor docker. After I ran my gitlab-ci.yml file , pipeline fail on step `docker info` during `before_script` with:

```
Running with gitlab-runner 13.10.0 (54944146)
  on docker-runner N2_yEgUD
Preparing the "docker" executor 00:07
Using Docker executor with image docker:19.03.0 ...
Starting service docker:19.03.0-dind ...
Pulling docker image docker:19.03.0-dind ...
Using docker image sha256:fd0c64832f7e46b63a180e6000dbba7ad7a63542c5764841cba73429ba74a39e for docker:19.03.0-dind with digest docker@sha256:442ac4b31375cbe617f31759b5199d240f11d5f430e54946575b274b2fb6f096 ...
Waiting for services to be up and running...
.............................................................................................
$ docker info
Client:
 Debug Mode: false
Server:
ERROR: error during connect: Get https://docker:2375/v1.40/info: dial tcp: lookup docker on 127.0.0.53:53: server misbehaving
errors pretty printing info
Cleaning up file based variables 00:01
ERROR: Job failed: exit code 1
```

I did a research on stack and official gitlab forum but none of the answers fix my issue:

- add to .toml -> `volume: ['/certs/client']`
- run against old: `docker:18.x.x` / `docker:18.x.x -dind` | `docker:stable` / `docker:dind`
- run with: `DOCKER_TLS_CERTDIR:""`
- run with/without:

```
  DOCKER_HOST: tcp://docker:2375/
  DOCKER_DRIVER: overlay2
  DOCKER_TLS_CERTDIR: "/certs"
```

- add endpoint to service:

```
services:
  - name: docker:dind
    entrypoint: ["env", "-u", "DOCKER_HOST"]
    command: ["dockerd-entrypoint.sh"]
```

Content of gitlab-runner toml

```
concurrent = 1
check_interval = 0
log_level = "debug"

[session_server]
  session_timeout = 1800

[[runners]]
  name = "docker-runner"
  url = "xxxxxxxx"
  token = "xxxxxxx"
  executor = "docker"
  [runners.cache]
    [runners.cache.s3]
    [runners.cache.gcs]
    [runners.cache.azure]
  [runners.docker]
    tls_verify = false
    privileged = true
    image = "docker:19.03.12"
    disable_cache = false
    volumes = ["/cache", "/certs/client"]
    network_mode = "host"
```

Content of gitlab-ci.yml

```
image: docker:19.03.0

services:
  - docker:19.03.0-dind

stages:
  - build
  - test_framework

variables:
  DOCKER_HOST: tcp://docker:2375/
  DOCKER_DRIVER: overlay2
  DOCKER_TLS_CERTDIR: "/certs" 
  CONTAINER_TEST_IMAGE: xxxx
  CONTAINER_RELEASE_IMAGE: xxxx

before_script:
  - docker info
  - docker login -u xxxx -p $CI_JOB_TOKEN xxxx

build:
  stage: build
  tags:
    - adm-docker
  script:
    - docker pull $CONTAINER_RELEASE_IMAGE || true
    - docker build -t $CONTAINER_TEST_IMAGE --cache-from $CONTAINER_RELEASE_IMAGE .
    - docker push $CONTAINER_TEST_IMAGE
  timeout: 1 hours

.test_commit: &test_commit
  stage: test_framework
  image: $CONTAINER_TEST_IMAGE
  tags:
    - adm-docker
  timeout: 1 hours
  artifacts:
    reports:
      junit: 'results/xunit.xml'
    expire_in: 1 day
  except:
    - master

test-unit:
  <<: *test_commit
  script:
    - python3 -m pytest --junitxml=results/xunit.xml test_unit/
```

Only one thing fix issue (workaround issue). When I add to .toml
`volume: ["/var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock"]`

But after that Iam loosing DIND possibility to run my gitlab-ci.yml with different image for `test` stage (without using under script: -docker run MY_IMAGE python3....).
Which is not what I want

`gitlab-runner under Ubuntu20 / Docker version 20.10.5, build 55c4c88`

Ive worked with very similar gitlab-ci.yml around 1Yr ago and there was no issue with docker executor

Any ideas/suggestions ?

Comment: Did you follow the official documentation https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/docker/using_docker_build.html#use-the-shell-executor? Could you please check step no. 4 and no. 5? Took a quick look at your `config.toml` and `gitlab-ci.yml`, but I think both are fine.

Comment: What do you mean about -> step no. 4 and no. 5. For which topic ?

Comment: Step no 4 and no 5 in the section "Use the shell executor" in the documentation:

(4) Add the gitlab-runner user to the docker group

(5) Verify that gitlab-runner has access to Docker

Comment: Iam using docker executor -> `docker run ...... gitlab/gitlab-runner`

Answer (score 0):

I was able to fix issue by changing flow of my gitlab-ci.yml

```
image: docker:19.03.5

services:
  - docker:19.03.5-dind

stages:
  - build
  - test_framework
  - release
    
variables:
  DOCKER_DRIVER: overlay2
  DOCKER_TLS_CERTDIR: ""
  CONTAINER_TEST_IMAGE: xxxxx
  CONTAINER_RELEASE_IMAGE: xxxxx

build:
  stage: build
  tags:
    - adm-docker
  before_script:
    - docker info
    - docker login -u xxxxx -p $CI_JOB_TOKEN xxxxx
  script:
    - docker pull $CONTAINER_RELEASE_IMAGE || true
    - docker build -t $CONTAINER_TEST_IMAGE --cache-from $CONTAINER_RELEASE_IMAGE .
    - docker push $CONTAINER_TEST_IMAGE
  timeout: 1 hours

.test_commit: &test_commit
  stage: test_framework
  tags:
    - adm-docker
  timeout: 1 hours
  artifacts:
    reports:
      junit: 'results/xunit.xml'
    expire_in: 1 day
  except:
    - master

test-unit:
  <<: *test_commit
  image: $CONTAINER_TEST_IMAGE 
  script: 
    - python3 -m pytest --junitxml=results/xunit.xml test_unit/
```

and toml

```
[[runners]]
  name = "docker-runner"
  url = xxxxx
  token = xxxxx
  executor = "docker"
  [runners.cache]
    [runners.cache.s3]
    [runners.cache.gcs]
    [runners.cache.azure]
  [runners.docker]
    tls_verify = false
    privileged = true
    image = "docker:19.03.12"
    disable_cache = false
    volumes = ["/cache", "/var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock"]
    network_mode = "host"
```

issue was fixed by `volumes = ["/cache", "/var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock"]`

and issue with test stage was cased by:

```
  before_script:
    - docker info
    - docker login -u xxxxx -p $CI_JOB_TOKEN xxxxx
```

in root structure of .yml file. I had to move it to `build stage`

I hope that will help ppl in the future